# finding largest value of x obtained from curve by implicit differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

Consider the curve defined by $x^2 + 2y^2 + 4 \beta x y = K $ with $K > 0$ and where $\beta$ is a (sufficiently small) parameter.  Assuming that the above can be used to define a function $x = G(y)$, use implicit differentiation to find out what is the largest value that $x$ can take on along this curve.

My attempt:
Since $x= G(y)$, the largest value of x is obtained when $G(y)$ is maximized, or when $G'(y)= 0$.  However, the given equation of the curve isn't $G(y)$ itself.  How do I express the curve equation as $G(y)$, or is there another way of finding the largest value of x along this curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If you differentiate the given expression above, say $F(x,y) - K = 0$, with respect to $y$, considering $x = x(y)$, you would have:

$$ 2 \, x(y) \, x'(y)  + 4 y + 4 \beta \, (x'(y) \, y + x(y) ) = 0,  $$

where use has been made of the chain rule.

If you need more help, let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi!  I'm still a little confused.  After differentiating the expression with respect to y, would the obtained result after differentiation (the equation you provided) be the function x= G(y)?  Or do I just assume that the expression provided can be defined as a function x= G(y), and since x= G(y) is the provided expression, I just need to find values of the derivative of the expression with respect to y that make x'(y)= 0?

Comment: Oh!  Never mind, I get it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help @shinify!